# Does retrieving less attributes consume less read unit on DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk, nosql

Assuming each item is greater than 4Kb, does retrieving less attributes by using Projection Expressions (so that the returned items are less than 4Kb each) save on read units?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As JaredHatfield pointed out, it does not.

The only use for Projections is that, instead of getting all item attributes back, you ask DynamoDB to return only some of them. This *might* save some network bandwidth and make client-side processing a bit simpler.

Relevant documentation [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.AccessingItemAttributes.html).